# Remove default Magento2 favicons from head

Tags: magento2

Magento2 inserts two favicons into the head: `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">` and `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">`.

Since I will add custom icons by myself in `default_head_blocks.xml`, I would like to remove the default two. I tried removing them via `<remove src="Magento_Theme::favicon.ico" />`, but this didn't work. I also tried to override the two icons by adding them to `default_head_blocks.xml` and using another file, but this didn't work either.

Comment: i think you can change favicon from admin panel.why through xml?

Comment: I don't want to change the favicons from the backend because you can only add two. I want to include several favicons to have an optimised favicon for a broad set of devices.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove the default favicons, but you can override them in a theme by adding your `favicon.ico` in the `<your_theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/web/` directory.
Other icons to be used as favicons must be also added here, and additionally specified in `default_head_blocks.xml`. Example: `<link src="Magento_Theme::favicon-32x32.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" />`

Comment: I'll guess that would be the best solution then.

Still, it's odd we're forced to keep using those two icons and don't have the possibility to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Favicons links being added by the method **prepareFavicon** in the class **Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer**
I also was requested to remove them so I came with this solution.

#### Solution:

In your customer module, create an after plugin on the method **prepareFavicon** in this class
**Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer**

Then get an instance from **Magento\Framework\View\Asset\GroupedCollection** and call the remove method on both favicon keys ('icon', 'shortcut-icon').

#### Steps:

1. Create your own custom module (Vendor_Module for example).
2. Add the plugin into the **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer">
        <plugin name="remove_default_favicon" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Renderer"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

3. Create the plugin class as explained below.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer as BaseRenderer;
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\GroupedCollection;

class Renderer
{
    /** @var GroupedCollection */
    private $pageAssets;

    public function __construct(GroupedCollection $pageAssets)
    {
        $this->pageAssets = $pageAssets;
    }

    public function afterPrepareFavicon(BaseRenderer $subject, $result)
    {
        $this->pageAssets->remove('icon');
        $this->pageAssets->remove('shortcut-icon');
    }
}
```

4. Run:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

And that's it, favicons links should disappear from the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can comment the **public function prepareFavicon()** parameters in **Renderer.php**
Should look this way:

```
public function prepareFavicon()
    {
       /** if ($this->pageConfig->getFaviconFile()) {
            $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                $this->pageConfig->getFaviconFile(),
                Generator\Head::VIRTUAL_CONTENT_TYPE_LINK,
                ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'icon', 'type' => 'image/png']],
                'icon'
            );
            $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                $this->pageConfig->getFaviconFile(),
                Generator\Head::VIRTUAL_CONTENT_TYPE_LINK,
                ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' => 'image/png']],
                'shortcut-icon'
            );
        } else {
            $this->pageConfig->addPageAsset(
                $this->pageConfig->getDefaultFavicon(),
                ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'icon', 'type' => 'image/png']],
                'icon'
            );
            $this->pageConfig->addPageAsset(
                $this->pageConfig->getDefaultFavicon(),
                ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' => 'image/png']],
                'shortcut-icon'
            );
        } */
    }
```